# Pycharm requirements.txt for multiple environments

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, requirements, anaconda3

I have two conda environments within one project: the base and a tensorflow environment. Both contain different packages. In PyCharm, I would like to generate environment-specific requirements.txt files, such that PyCharm automatically recognizes which packages are required for the environment that is currently activated.

I tried Tools/SyncPythonRequirements but this only generates one requirements.txt file which is neither appropriate for the base nor the tensorflow environment. Is it possible to assign a requirements.txt for each environment?
I use Anaconda3 (Python 3.8).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why just not use two environments for your project? (every script can be associated with a different env). On your env, you can select which requirements.txt you want to use (it is common to have few, with a dash and extra description).

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain your last sentence more in depth? Particularly, how can I select which requirements.txt I want to use?

Comment: I do not know. I install/update the requirements file with pip (not directly from PyCharm), and I do it seldom. And for such tasks, if I do it repeatly, I create few new "runa" with appropriate environment and pip command. Ideally putting as hock in git would be better (and I'm sure people did it), but I do no have many changes in requirements (and I often forget to update it)